# npm install shows colors during install on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, npm

I'm trying to perform `npm install` in a Dockerfile, but even when supposedly disabling the colors, color codes still seem to appear in the Dockerhub build logs.

What might I be doing wrong?

You can find the Dockerfile with the build details on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/amcsi/szeremi/builds/btk4utf3whezxqhnbzpkhyw/

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
MAINTAINER  Attila Szeremi <attila+webdev@szeremi.com>
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN cd /src
# Copy just the package.json file file as a cache step.
COPY package.json /src/package.json
# Disable progress so npm would install faster.
# Disable colors, because Dockerhub can't display them.
# Install NPM packages excluding the dev dependencies.
RUN npm set progress=false && npm set color=false && npm install --production

COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Sample of the build script's output:

```
Step 3 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 4a8ec4902bee
 ---> ce66cec7780b
Removing intermediate container 4a8ec4902bee
Step 4 : RUN cd /src
 ---> Running in 561c6d10cdb8
 ---> c12b27e7c01a
Removing intermediate container 561c6d10cdb8
Step 5 : COPY package.json /src/package.json
 ---> ebbb940c8911
Removing intermediate container c39be008ad46
Step 6 : RUN npm set progress=false && npm set color=false && npm install --production
 ---> Running in c9ebee32f367
[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91mit worked if it ends with[0m[91m ok
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91musing[0m[91m npm@3.3.12
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91musing[0m[91m node@v5.5.0
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91mconfig[0m[91m set "progress" "false"
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m ok 
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91mit worked if it ends with[0m[91m ok
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91musing[0m[91m npm@3.3.12
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91musing[0m[91m node@v5.5.0
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91mconfig[0m[91m set "color" "false"
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91mok[0m[91m 
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91mit worked if it ends with[0m[91m ok
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91musing[0m[91m npm@3.3.12
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91minfo[0m[91m [0m[91musing[0m[91m node@v5.5.0
```

Comment: Did you disable the colors in the host's terminal?

Comment: There are no colors in this display terminal, which is Docker Hub's output view of how the steps in the Dockerfile went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was `npm install 2>&1` which I found here: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/225

Answer (score 0):

`FROM node` means [node 6.5](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/910443c39c80291f0bf24712d8d94279cf15b7b5/6.5/Dockerfile) (currently latest in Sept 2016)

As mentioned in [issue 225](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/225), that comes with a progress bar (that you tried to disable) *and* a spinner.

Try the simple test case:

```
FROM node:6.4.0

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PROGRESS false
ENV NPM_CONFIG_SPIN false

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install express
```

Or by copying a .npmrc with:

```
progress=false
spin=false
```

Or by adding `--color false` directly to the  `npm install` command:

```
 npm --color false install --production
```

If nothing works, re-open issue 225, as it is the most recent bug report on that issue.

Or consider running the job in Jenkins with the [AnsiColor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) to at least support f

---

Since this answer (Oct. 2016), the issue 225 mentions:

> Problem is that your Jenkins just does not support ANSI escape sequences in the console output.
>   All output on STDERR in your Dockerfile is printed in red by docker build. So as mentioned by @tianon just use the AnsiColor+Plugin to fix this.

So one way to work around this is to ignore any output, as mentioned by [Zack Steinkamp](https://github.com/zsteinkamp) in [this comment of the issue 225](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/225#issuecomment-333570453) with `RUN npm install 2>&1`.

Comment: As you can see, color is already set to false in my Dockerfile. So that doesn't work.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi Yes, hence my other suggestions.

Comment: It didn't work, no change. See https://hub.docker.com/r/amcsi/skill-builder/builds/brhzu6kukthmhdntdrjrdxf/ Compare it to the one before your suggestions: https://hub.docker.com/r/amcsi/skill-builder/builds/bggwmmdjkhwpekfjnyq8gea/